# Missing Identifier in Dart

Tags: android, dart

I am new to coding and I am trying to write a simple app that would basicaly flip the top card of a deck and place it face up next to it.

I keep getting errors like "missing_identifier".
Below is my code, and I would really appreciate if I can get help getting it to work. "easy to understand" replies for a newbie would be appreciated.

Cheers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


class Card {
  final String cardName;
  final int cardValue;
  bool revealed;

  Card({required this.cardName, required this.cardValue, this.revealed = false});
}
final List<Card> deck = [
  Card(cardName: "Joker", cardValue: 0),
  Card(cardName: "Joker", cardValue: 0),
  Card(cardName: "King of Hearts", cardValue: 13),
  Card(cardName: "King of Hearts", cardValue: 13),
  // Add more cards here
  child: CardPile(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    card: card,
),

];
final List<Card> discardPile = [];


class CardPile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Card card;
  
  CardPile({required this.card, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        if (card.revealed)
          Image.asset("assets/images/card_${card.cardName}.png"),
        else
          Image.asset("assets/images/card_back.png"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _GameScreenState extends State<GameScreen> {
  final List<Card> deck = [
    Card(cardName: "Joker", cardValue: 0),
    Card(cardName: "Joker", cardValue: 0),
    Card(cardName: "King of Hearts", cardValue: 13),
    Card(cardName: "King of Hearts", cardValue: 13),
    // Add more cards here
  ];
  final List<Card> discardPile = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _shuffleDeck();
  }

  void _shuffleDeck() {
    deck.shuffle();
  }

  void _onRestart() {
    setState(() {
      _shuffleDeck();
      discardPile.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(),
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: deck.map((card) => GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    deck.remove(card);
                                    discardPile.add(card);
card.revealed = true;
});
},
child: CardPile(
card: card,
)))
.toList(),
),
),
),
Positioned(
right: 0,
top: 0,
bottom: 0,
child: Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
child: ListView(
children: discardPile
.map((card) => CardPile(
card: card,
))
.toList(),
),
),
),
if (deck.isEmpty)
Center(
child: RaisedButton(
onPressed: _onRestart,
child: Text("Restart"),
),
)
],
),
),
Spacer(),
Container(
width: double.infinity,
height: 50,
child: RaisedButton(
onPressed: _shuffleDeck,
child: Text(
"Play",
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
),
),
),
],
),
),
);
}
}

class GameScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_GameScreenState createState() => _GameScreenState();
}

void main() {runApp(MaterialApp(
home: GameScreen(),
));
}
```

I tried to remove the "else" statement, define "key" and "RaisedButton". I am lost

Comment: There are a bunch of syntactic problems.  To get you started: 1. The global `deck` list has `child: CardPile(...)`, which is nonsensical as an element to a `List`.  Copy/paste error? 2. When using collection-`if`, do not put a comma before the `else`.  That is, it should be `if (card.revealed) Image.asset(...) else Image.asset(...)`.  IMO it'd be even better to use `Image.asset(card.revealed ? 'assets/images/card_${card.cardName}.png' : 'assets/images/card_back.png')`.  Also, you shouldn't need a `Stack` widget if its children is a `List` with only one element.  Just return that element.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Yes, I did copy and paste this code and I am trying to understand what it does.
I understand what I am reading and what the code is trying to do but I wouldn't be able to write this code or make it work by myself.
I did remove the "," after the if statement and it fixed that issue. But I am not sure to get what to do about the child: CardPile. Do I simply not need it?

Comment: The `child: CardPile(...)` part makes no sense, so I can't tell what it's trying to do, but you probably should remove it. It seems like a mistake that you made when copying and pasting (i.e. two separate sections of code accidentally pasted together).

Comment: Thank you!!! I did remove this part and I am now working on the rest of the code. I will try to fix what I can on my own and I will post what I came up with.